# How to get the style name and state name of a clicked element in React Native?

Tags: react-native

**In the following, first example** how do I check if the clickable element `TouchableWithoutFeedback` has the style named `EntryBlock1`?

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.EntryBlock1} onPress={() => this.CheckIfHasStyles()}>
        <View style={styles.redundantWrapperNumber1}>
          <Text style={styles.redundantWrapperNumber2}>Click To Test For Style</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.EntryBlock2} onPress={() => this.CheckIfHasStyle()}>
        <View style={styles.redundantWrapperNumber1}>
          <Text style={styles.redundantWrapperNumber2}>Click To Test For Style</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    ); // end return
  } // end render
```

**In the 2nd example**, how can I check if `TouchableWithoutFeedback` has the state name `EntryBlock1` ?

```js
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      EntryBlock1: [styles.entryBlockButton, styles.entryBlockButtonMin],
      EntryBlock2: [styles.entryBlockButton, styles.entryBlockButtonMax],
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={this.state.EntryBlock1} onPress={() => this.CheckIfHasStateName()}>
        <View style={styles.redundantWrapperNumber1}>
          <Text style={styles.redundantWrapperNumber2}>Click To Test For Style</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    ); // end return
```

**What I've Tried**

Different stuff along the lines of the following..

```js
  CheckIfHasStyles =()=> {
    var object = this.state;
    var stringifiedObject = JSON.stringify(object);
    var slicedObject = stringifiedObject.slice(2, 13);
    if (slicedObject === 'EntryBlock1') {
      alert('success');
    } else {
      alert('failure');
    }
  }
```

.. which actually works for one very specific example, but not when I have multiple state names as this.state gets all of them in one object and not just the state of the element clicked.

Note: My question is solely about getting attributes and their values. It is to help me develop a style of toggling styles on elements but I am only looking for attribute stuff in these answers as I would like to use attributes, if possible, for more than just toggling in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as parameter to your function directly like this:

```
     render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.EntryBlock1} onPress={() => this.CheckIfHasStyles('EntryBlock1')}>
        <View style={styles.redundantWrapperNumber1}>
          <Text style={styles.redundantWrapperNumber2}>Click To Test For Style</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.EntryBlock2} onPress={() => this.CheckIfHasStyle('EntryBlock2')}>
        <View style={styles.redundantWrapperNumber1}>
          <Text style={styles.redundantWrapperNumber2}>Click To Test For Style</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    ); 
  }
```

and check if you are receiving any parameter in your function and do what you want
based on If-else condition

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I pass parameters for some other areas of the app but for this case I'm trying to change the styles on press by updating the state. I should have maybe mentioned the reason for it is that I'm trying to come up with a simple toggle style system that I can understand and use in this app and on future ones. So what I'm trying to do is get the current state/style (which will change onpress) so that I can then do the if/else stuff based on that.